# Remove showing page numbering from ToC and Part pages

Tags: table-of-contents, page-numbering, double-sided, report

I searched for a solution and found some of them but they didn't work  for  me. I don't know why.
I have multimapge ToC and want to remove showing the page numbers on them. I also would like to remove pages numbers on the pages where the \part name is showed.
My MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,twoside]{report}
\usepackage[top=25mm, bottom=25mm, outer=15mm, inner=35mm]{geometry}
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.15}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{polski}
\usepackage[polish]{babel}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\part{XXX}
\lipsum[1]
\chapter{xxx}
\lipsum[1]
\section{1234}
\lipsum[1]
\part{XXX}
\lipsum[1]
\chapter{xxx}
\lipsum[1]
\section{1234}
\lipsum[1]
\part{XXX}
\lipsum[1]
\chapter{xxx}
\lipsum[1]
\section{1234}
\lipsum[1]
\part{XXX}
\lipsum[1]
\chapter{xxx}
\lipsum[1]
\section{1234}
\lipsum[1]
\part{XXX}
\lipsum[1]
\chapter{xxx}
\lipsum[1]
\section{1234}
\lipsum[1]
\part{XXX}
\lipsum[1]
\chapter{xxx}
\lipsum[1]
\section{1234}
\lipsum[1]
\part{XXX}
\lipsum[1]
\chapter{xxx}
\lipsum[1]
\section{1234}
\lipsum[1]
\part{XXX}
\lipsum[1]
\chapter{xxx}
\lipsum[1]
\section{1234}
\lipsum[1]


\end{document}
```

Comment: Have you tried `\thispagestyle{empty}`? Also, have a look at this page: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/191181/part-and-thispagestyleempty.

Comment: yes, I tried, but on multipage ToC it removes page numbering just only on the one page of ToC, and do not remove pages from `/part` pages

Answer (score 1):

**OPTION #1 (ToC only):**
Instead of:

```
\tableofcontents
\thispagestyle{empty}
```

you can use:

```
\pagestyle{empty}
{
  \renewcommand{\thispagestyle}[1]{}
  \tableofcontents
}
\clearpage
\pagestyle{plain}
```

This eliminates page numbers from both pages of your ToC and starts your Chapter 1 at page 3 (includes invisible ToC pages). See [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/180877/121944) for explanation.

**OPTION #2 (ToC only):**

Another option that works, [from here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/41558/121944), is to use:

```
\cleardoublepage
\pagenumbering{gobble}
\tableofcontents
\cleardoublepage
\pagenumbering{arabic}
```

This starts your Chapter 1 at page 1.

**OPTION #3 (ToC and Part):**
And of course you can include `\part` in the page gobbling party like so:

```
\cleardoublepage
\pagenumbering{gobble}
\tableofcontents

\part{XXX}
\lipsum[1]
\cleardoublepage
\pagenumbering{arabic}
```

Comment: Thank you, it works. I used 1'st option for ToC only, and another solution to remove page numbering from `\part`, because your require (option 3) adding text before all `\part` declarations. Thank you! P.S. I think, used wrong words to search for this solution

Comment: I don't think that the third solution is a good one for two reasons. The first is that OP has to type `\pagenumbering{gobble}\part{..}\pagenumbering{arabic}` for each `\part`, the second is that gobble reset the counter of the pages and I don't think that this is what OP wants.

Comment: @EmilKob The fact that his third solution required adding text before and after each part could be avoided redefining `\part`.

Answer (score 1):

In order to have part pages empy you can add in your preamble

```
\makeatletter % changes the catcode of @ to 11
\renewcommand\part{%
  \if@openright
    \cleardoublepage
  \else
    \clearpage
  \fi
  \thispagestyle{empty}%
  \if@twocolumn
    \onecolumn
    \@tempswatrue
  \else
    \@tempswafalse
  \fi
  \null\vfil
  \secdef\@part\@spart}
\makeatother
```

That is simply the definition of part made in report.cls but with `\thispagestyle{plain}` changed to `\thispagestyle{empty}`

Comment: Nothe that this resolve only the second part of your question. I suggest you to take a look at the answer by AML. But pay attention to the page numbering. I think that his first option combined with mine is what you are looking for but maybe I'm wrong.

Comment: Yes I know, i used 1'st option from AML's answer for ToC. Thanks!